# (Seaborn)making tick figures larger

Tags: seaborn

My code used 'Paper' style as below.By using set_theme(), making larger or smaller overall plots is possible.
My goal is to make tick figures 1.00, 1.25 .. at the vertical axis lager. How to modify my code below?

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


data=pd.DataFrame({'val':[1, 1, 2, 2.1, 2, 2.5, 2.3],'site':['a','a','a','b','b','b','b'],
      'X2':[4, 5 ,6 ,10, 10, 11, 11], 'X3':[100,100,200,200,200,300,300],
     'applydate':[1101,1102,1201,1202,1204,1204,1204],
     'X1':['b','b','h','b','b','h','h'] })


def my_scatter(x,y, **kwargs):
     plt.scatter(x=x, y=y,**kwargs)
     mx = np.mean(x);my= np.mean(y);


sns.set_context("paper")  # the 'paper'style
g = sns.FacetGrid(data,col='site',height=3)
g.map(my_scatter, "X2", "val",s=100, alpha=.5)
g.add_legend()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With added 4 line as below, even fontsize of title changing was  possible.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np   
data=pd.DataFrame({'val':[1, 1, 2, 2.1, 2, 2.5, 2.3],'site':['a','a','a','b','b','b','b'],
      'X2':[4, 5 ,6 ,10, 10, 11, 11], 'X3':[100,100,200,200,200,300,300],
     'applydate':[1101,1102,1201,1202,1204,1204,1204],
     'X1':['b','b','h','b','b','h','h'] })    

def my_scatter(x,y, **kwargs):
     plt.scatter(x=x, y=y,**kwargs)
     mx = np.mean(x);my= np.mean(y);   

sns.set_context("paper")  # the 'paper'style
g = sns.FacetGrid(data,col='site',height=3)
g.map(my_scatter, "X2", "val",s=100, alpha=.5)
g.add_legend()
# added 4 lines: tick, title font size
for k, ax in zip(g.axes_dict.keys(), g.axes_dict.values()):
    ax.set_xlabel(None,fontsize=20); ax.set_ylabel(None,fontsize=20);   
    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize = 20); ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize = 20)
    ax.set_title(k,fontsize=20);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the grid axes with the `axes` attribute (see [doc](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html)) and use the `set_yticklabels` method ([link](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels.html)):

```
g.axes[0, 0].set_yticklabels(g.axes[0, 0].get_yticklabels(), fontsize=14)
```